# How to use filter on a range of hostname in wireshark?

Tags: wireshark

I am new to wireshark and spend some time but couldn't find the filter for my use-case.

I have lot of hosts which start with

```
12.xyz.com
13.xyz.com
18.xyz.com
23.xyz.com
11.abc.com
12.abc.com
19.abc.com
1.pqr.com
2.pqr.com
3.pqr.com
```

and their ip range collide with each other that means I cannot use ip filter by putting a ip-range like this `dst.addr==192.168.0.0/24`.

Is there a way I can pass the filter like this
`dst.addr == *.abc.com` in wireshark to filter all the host with common hostname.

Comment: since wireshark filters on the network package level, you would like wireshark to do the hostname to IP address lookups for you and create an IP address list where it filters by? A reverse lookup might also work: take an IP address from a package, do a reverse lookup to find out all hostnames and check if the pattern matches. I think both ways are not really "quick and easy".

Comment: Not sure if my question is confusing or not. But my ask is simple - How we can put a filter on a range of hostname or with a common prefix/suffix using wireshark. I believe this option is not available in wireshark but if it is - I would like to use it to save lot of time.

Comment: I think this is just not an easy task to implement: a hostname can resolve to multiple IP addresses (via a round robin system), and the same IP address could be resolved by multiple hostnames. But wireshark can only filter by IP addresses, because those are the data that "goes over the wire". So a dynamic resolution from IP addresses to match a hostname filter would be probably too resource intensive. Better create a script that generates a filter with a huge list of IP addresses. Also don't forget that you cannot resolve a domain name with wildcards.